# xpath function to serialize node?

Tags: xpath

I am using a stack at the moment where I don't have direct access to the XML and can only pull through xpath selectors. By default it will return 'string()' if the response is not text.

'string()' will concatenate all text nodes. I am looking for a way to return the serialization of a node so text + tags + attributes.

I can't see anything that looks like this but it seems like an obvious thing to want so I recon I am not looking in the right place .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you work in an XPath or XQuery 3.0 environment with http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-serialize being supported (or a similar extension function) you won't have access to such a function.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear but thanks. Think PHP will take a while to get there.

Comment: You can take advantage of another XPath/XQuery engine from PHP, most XML Databases and XQuery engines offer interfaces to PHP without giving up performance and are not too complicated to set up.